# Pick certain item from javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript

For example I have an array of object

```
var json = [
  {
    id: 23,
    name: 'zyan doe',
    email: 'zyan.doe@gmail.com'
    job_titlte: 'software engineer',
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    name: 'john doe',
    email: 'john.doe@gmail.com'
    job_titlte: 'support engineer',
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'jane doe',
    email: 'jane.doe@gmail.com'
    job_titlte: 'software engineer',
  }
];
```

I want this array with only id and names, like

```
[
  {
    id: 23,
    name: 'zyan doe'
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    name: 'john doe'
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: 'jane doe'
  }
]
```

I need to do it with pure javascript. I have searched for a while but could not figure out. How to do it.

Comment: Take a look at `Array.prototype.map()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

```
var res = json.map(function(itm){
  return {id:itm.id, name:itm.name}
});
```

Comment: FYI - in ES2015+ you can do `var res = json.map(({id, name}) => ({id, name}));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to 'transform' each item in an array, creating a new array of the the transformed items:

```
function getOnlyIdAndName(item) {
    return {id:item.id, name:item.name};
}

var newArrayOfTransformedItems = json.map(getOnlyIdAndName);
```